# Trying to understand how an adjusted repeating Mac Calendar event can be manipulated in Applescript

Tags: macos, calendar, applescript

When I use AppleScript for a repeating event, I am able to reference each recurrence of an event, even if one or more of the repeated occurrences is canceled.

What I am having trouble with is how a "moved" occurrence is stored.  So, this is one of the occurrences that is not at the same time but moved.

Imagine a weekly event at 9am every Monday.  If on the third week, I drag the event in the calendar app to be at 10am rather than 9am on the Monday.  I do not see anywhere in the event metadata that shows me the moved occurrence of the event.

I would appreciate any pointers.

I have tried looking at all the relevant event metadata.  I am using Script Debugger as my tool.

Here is the code.  I not only changed the time of the moved event, I also changed the name.  This is looking for the name.

```
tell application "Calendar"
    
    set sourceCalID to calendar id "4AA1E22C-0472-44D1-A582-31A7310AF9B4"
    
    set howManyEvents to number of event of sourceCalID
    
    set the_events to every event of sourceCalID
    
    
    repeat with current_event in the_events
        set summaryEvent to summary of current_event
        
        log summaryEvent
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

Comment: Please show your relevant code.

Comment: Added to the end of the original post.